# Why can't I cast an object-var of a long to a double?

Tags: c#, casting, type-conversion

I'm new to C# (but I know C++, JavaScript and Java) and I'm using JSON.net to parse a JSON file to a `Dictionary<string, object>`. Now I'm trying to store a value which was parsed as a `long` into a double variable. (I looked at the inspector and it says the dictionary value is of type `object{long}`.)

```
object obj = 123L;
double dbl = (double)obj;
```

Which gives me an `InvalidCastException`. I experimented a bit and found out that `Convert.ToDouble(obj)` works out just fine. I looked around and couldn't find anything about that difference between casting and Convert-ing. Also:

```
var v = 123L;
double dbl = (double)v;
```

This works perfectly. I guess that's because in this case, var is turned into Int64 at compile time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because that's an [unboxing conversion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/b95fkada%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). In order to cast a boxed `long` to a `double`, you can first unbox it, then actually convert it, for example: (not tested)

```
object obj = 123L;
double dbl = (double)(long)obj;
```

The second snippet works for the reason you identified.

Comment: I see, so using "object" as a variable type creates a reference to the value. Is there a way to unbox the value to a double if it is a double and to a long if it is a long?

Comment: @Jacque How do plan to store an arbitrary unboxed value? In `var`? Remember that `var` is resolved at compile time. If there was such an expression to unbox an object to it's own type, what would the type of such an expression be? It can't be object, as you would end up with what you began with. If you want to access the data inside the instance, you can -**NOT RECOMMENDED**- use `TypedReference`. If you want to pass this object to method overloads that take both `double` and `long`, use it as `dynamic`.

Comment: @JacqueGoupil yes, but not in a useful way as far as I know. Maybe you need generics and get rid of the boxing?

Comment: @harold Good enough, I was just curious. I'll just stick to Convert.toDouble for now.

Answer (score 2):

When you cast an object to a value type, you *unbox* it. Unboxing is only possible to the type of the value type. As the type of the object is long, you can't unbox it to double. Check the [Convert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert_methods%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class:

```
double dbl = Convert.ToDouble(obj, null);
```